# How to create a linked data source with document libraries based on the same template?

Tags: 2013, document-library, data-view-web-part, list-template

I'm using SharePoint Foundation 2013 and I use SP Designer and Visual Studio 2013 to my needs. But there are several things which i don't get.

I have a number of libraries which use the same template. I want to create a linked data source, that would contain them all, and if I add a library based on this template, the library would be added to the data sorce. Is it possible?

I tried creating linked data souces, but the view that it brings by default is limited(no sorting, etc.). How can it be modified?